# VBA Excel code for barcode scanning that returns time scanned

Tags: vba, excel

I have this spreadsheet that I use to scan barcodes of files. I have got the macro to return the dates the file is scanned-in or out, but also want to avoid barcodes being scanned more than once in quick succession.

This is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A3000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim lc As Long
    With Application
      .EnableEvents = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
       lc = Cells(Target.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

       If lc = 1 Then
         Cells(Target.Row, lc + 2) = Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy h:mm")
       ElseIf lc > 2 Then
         Cells(Target.Row, lc + 1) = Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy h:mm")        
       End If

      .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

I need help to put in a timer to return a msgbox when a file is scanned more than once in a space of 60seconds for example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a public variable to store the last scan time + 1 minute, and if the current time is less that time then just exit the sub prematurely, if its good to go just run the code again and update the time

```
Public NextScan as Double

Public Sub Test
   If NOT NextScan < DateTime.Now Then Exit Sub

   'YOUR CODE

   NextScan = DateTime.Now + DateTime.TimeSerial(0, 1, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Paul. I tried to add the code to my current code but it doesn't seem to work. Where should I add the code or adjust the code to make it work?

Comment: sry i couldnt reply sooner i was away...if you put the first line 'If NOT Nextscan......' right at the top of your sub and the other line 'NextScan = .....' right at the bottom then of course put the 'Public NextScan......' right at the top of the Code module, not inside a sub or function.

Comment: you may need some code to handle the input on the sheet, maybe add something to erase the data put there by the scanner until its the correct time.